# SQLite query slower on another database with same structure

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

**Question**: how can the query be so much slower on my database?

I got 2 databases with the same column structure, and I run the following query:

```
start = time.time()
q2 = cursor.execute('SELECT x, y, z FROM table WHERE id=?', id_tuple )
print(" {}".format(time.time() - start))
```

Output for **my created database**:

```
  0%|          | 0/82039 [00:00<?, ?it/s] 0.0269162654876709
  0%|          | 1/82039 [00:05<123:58:32,  5.44s/it] 0.0199429988861084
  0%|          | 2/82039 [00:06<92:32:50,  4.06s/it]  0.023944377899169922
  0%|          | 3/82039 [00:06<69:11:56,  3.04s/it] 0.01447606086730957
```

Output for **another database** (where I copied the structure from):

```
  0%|          | 0/316523 [00:00<?, ?it/s] 0.002210378646850586
  0%|          | 1/316523 [00:01<115:36:26,  1.31s/it] 0.0019009113311767578
  0%|          | 2/316523 [00:04<168:48:36,  1.92s/it] 0.0021212100982666016
  0%|          | 3/316523 [00:05<131:20:58,  1.49s/it] 0.002077817916870117
```

At the end of each line the time for the query is shown.

My performance is really slow since I need to repeat that query a lot of times

Comment: Did you copy any indexes?

Comment: Hardware?  Networks?  Data size?  Indexes?  There are lots of reasons.

Comment: Benchmarking between different CPU environments is a tough art. There is no blanket reason for differences of same code. Plus a database table's column structure can be same but rows differ in number.